# Fubini theorem to calculate iterated integral, counting and Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

With the counting measure on  $\mathbb{N}$, and the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, consider their product
measure space and the function:

$f(x,n) = \begin{cases} 
      -2^n  & \text{ if $x\in[2^{-n}, 2^{-n+1})$ } \\
      2^n & \text{ if $x\in [0, 2^{-n})$} \\
      0 & \text {otherwise} 
\end{cases}$

I have a problem understanding how to compute the two iterated integrals. Could someone show me how to do one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n$, $x\mapsto f(x,n)$ is a simple function and:
$$\int_{\Bbb R}f(x,n)\,dx=2^n(2^{-n}-0)-2^n(2^{-n+1}-2^{-n})=\cdots$$